# Functional on Triangulation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\Omega$ a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\mathcal{T} :=\{T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_N\}$ a triangulation of $\Omega$, i.e,

1. $\overline{T}_i$ is a triangle with non empty inner, $\forall j\in\{1,\ldots, N\}$
2. $T_i\cap T_j=\varnothing$
3. $\overline{\Omega} = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^N\overline{T}_j$

Define the Hilbert space:
$$H\ :=\ \left\{v \in [L^2(\Omega)]^2 :\; \mbox{div}(v)\in L^2(T_j),\; \forall j\in\{1,\ldots,N\}\right\},$$
with the inner product
$$\langle v,w\rangle_H\ =\ \int_{\Omega}v\cdot w\;dx + \sum_{j=1}^N\int_{T_j}\mbox{div}(v)\mbox{div}(w)\;dx,\;\; \forall\ u,w\in H.$$
Now, consider the linear functional $F:H\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$F(w)\ :=\ \sum_{j=1}^N\int_{T_j}\mbox{div}(w)\;dx,$$
then, show that
$$|F(w)|\ \leq\ |\Omega|^{1/2}\|w\|_H,\;\;\; \forall\; w\in H.$$

---

---

I have done this:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|F(w)| & = & \left|\sum_{j=1}^N\int_{T_j}\mbox{div}(w)\;dx\right|\ \leq\ \sum_{j=1}^N\left|\int_{T_j}1\cdot\mbox{div}(w)\;dx\right|\\
 & \leq & \sum_{j=1}^N\|1\|_{L^2(T_j)}\cdot\|\mbox{div}(w)\|_{L^2(T_j)}\; \mbox{ (Cauchy-Schwarz)}\\
 & \leq & \left(\sum_{j=1}^N\|1\|_{L^2(T_j)}\right)\|w\|_H\\
 & = & \left[\sum_{j=1}^N\left(\int_{T_j}1\;dx\right)^{1/2}\right]\|w\|_H\\
 & = & \left[\sum_{j=1}^N|T_j|^{1/2}\right]\|w\|_H
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, if I am right, I don't know how prove that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^N|T_j|^{1/2} \leq |\Omega|^{1/2}$, because I understand that $|\Omega| = \sum\limits_{j=1}^N|T_j|$, right?

Please, help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third inequality is wrong. You should estimate
$$\sum_{j=1}^N \|1\|_{L^2(T_j)} \, \|\mathrm{div}(w)\|_{L^2(T_j)}
\le
\Big(\sum_{j=1}^N \|1\|_{L^2(T_j)}^2\Big)^{1/2} \, \Big(\sum_{j=1}^N \|\mathrm{div}(w)\|_{L^2(T_j)}^2\Big)^{1/2}
$$
by using Cauchy-Schwarz in $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: Ohhh, that's great thanks so much. By the way, the third inequality is correct, it's from the definition of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$, but is not usefull :)

Comment: The "wrong" was meant in the sense that you loose to much in your estimate there.